# Set of injective operators is a dense residual set in $\mathcal{B}(\mathfrak{X})$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

Let $\mathfrak{X}$ be a Banach space and $\mathcal{B}(\mathfrak{X})$ the set of bounded linear operators mapping $\mathfrak{X}$ to $\mathfrak{X}$. In [1] below it is shown that the set of invertible operators is not necessarily dense in $\mathcal{B}(\mathfrak{X})$, although it is well known that it is an open set. In [2], it is shown that the set of injections (I suppose we may call this $\mathcal{I}(\mathfrak{X})$) is not necessarily open in $\mathcal{B}(\mathfrak{X})$.

My question is on how "common" injectiveness is in $\mathcal{B}(\mathfrak{X})$. In particular, the results above leave open the possibility that $\mathcal{I}(\mathfrak{X})$ is a dense $G_\delta$ set, and so topologically generic. In either case, it would be interesting to know whether density or the $G_\delta$ condition hold. I believe that the spectral theorem already implies that normal operators on Hilbert spaces may be approximated by injective operators (see for instance [3]). Any results that you guys know of would be appreciated!

[1] [Showing that $\mathcal{G}(\ell_2)$ is not dense in $\mathcal{B}(\ell_2)$ via the right shift](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1047062/showing-that-mathcalg-ell-2-is-not-dense-in-mathcalb-ell-2-via-the)

[2] [Do bounded linear operators on a Banach space which are injective or have dense range form an open subspace?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2147010/do-bounded-linear-operators-on-a-banach-space-which-are-injective-or-have-dense)

[3] [The set of invertible normal operator is dense in the set of normal operator](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2564944/the-set-of-invertible-normal-operator-is-dense-in-the-set-of-normal-operator)